# Why Lazy Load Module Route not include Core module component?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

Lazy load module route not able to use core module components and directive why? I create a Shell Component which I use when creating child route of the lazy-loaded module. but when i navigate to lazy load module, they said there is no shell component exist in @Ngmodule.

please explain why this happened ? if try to import core module again in lazy load module then error shown is **you can only import core module in App module**

**Update(reproduce bug)**

**Stackblitz**: ***https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2kwxtw***

Comment: It seems you try you follow the common pattern of SharedModule and CoreModule.

But the CodeModule should only contain application-wide Injectable (services) for which you want to ensure singleton-ness. 

Your CoreModule must never export components. Its the job for the SharedModule.

Comment: Thanks, @PierreMallet, but what is the reason, why I can not use core module component in the lazy loaded module? Please provide some explanation that will help me.

Comment: Hi!! can you create a  sample at stackblitz.com and link it from here. It will increase your chances of getting help

Comment: Any angular module ( lazy loaded of not ) can only use component declared in it ( private component ) or components which are exported in a module that your module is importing ( public component ). That's the angular way. You should look at https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules and https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules to get a better understanding of this.

Comment: @alt255, Please check the stackblitz link.

Comment: @AnkitRana this might be helpful: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#forroot

Comment: @alt255, I know Core Module is used to create singleton service, but why we are not able to use the exported component of a core module with a lazy loaded module, instead of core module component working fine if I used in the non-lazy loaded module.

Comment: @PierreMallet comment helped me solve 'ShellComponent' not loaded issue. Any module using Route.withShell should declare ShellComponent or import module declaring and exporting it. Thanks